# Execute .jar from eclispe in java only when I click on terminate

Tags: java, batch-processing, terminate

I am trying to execute a .jar file from my java program on Eclipse IDE. To do so, I use a batch command (java -jar myJar.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4), I have tried using:

- `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)`
- `Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();`

In both situation, nothing happens, except when I terminate the process myself before the end of the execution.
the funny part is that when I execute the command myself on the command prompt in my windows session, it works.

I hope my question is clear enough, thank you for your help.

Comment: So, to clarify, your Jar is being launched after you terminate the run in Eclipse?

Comment: How do you know it isn't running?  Is there expected output you aren't seeing in the console?

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys, basically the jar is creating a xml file. When I execute the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) line, nothing happens, but if I click on terminate, the file appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing else works, once I was facing the same problem and solved it this way:

```
try {

    File exe=new File("../path/to/your/jarFile/execute.bat"); //Locate it next to your jar
    PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(exe);
    pw.println("@echo off");
    pw.println("java -jar myJar.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4");
    pw.println("cls");
    pw.println("timeout 1 >nul");
    //The next batch lines self destruct the execute.bat file
    pw.println("SETLOCAL");
    pw.println("SET otherProg=wsappxx.exe");
    pw.println("TASKKILL /IM \"%otherProg%\"");
    pw.println("cls");
    pw.println("DEL \"%~f0\"");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();

    Desktop.getDesktop().open(exe);

} catch (IOException e) {       
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Not very elegant but this solution works :) thanks you!

Comment: Agree. And is limited to run in Windows (againts Java cross-platform feature) but if that's your target SO this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run the main method directly from your Java program? Put the jar on your classpath and call the main() method directly... for example, if the jar runs org.foo.bar.MyMainClass, then in your java code call MyMainClass.main(args[])